# jQuery to check if element exists in a XML

Tags: jquery, xml, forms

I have an XML file with a list of Zip Codes:

```xml
<zipcodes>
    <zipcode>29102265</zipcode>
    ... more Zip Codes ...
</zipcodes>
```

I am trying that, at the end of the form validation, the value of a form input is used to check if the Zip Code is in the list. I am using this plugin for validation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I am also using this plugin to handle de form submit: https://github.com/malsup/form

My jQuery function looks like this:

```js
submitHandler: function(form){
  var zipCode = $(input).val()
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'xml/zips.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    succes: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('zipcodes').children().each( function() {
        if ( $(this).content === zipCode ) {
          console.log( 'okay' )
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

I am knew to XML and kind of lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're almost there. Try with this:

```
$(this).text() // -> 29102265, ..., ...,
```

That way you'll get the value of the xml tag

Comment: I think it has to do with your validation. With `===` you're also validating the data type. So... `$(this).text()` results in `"29102265"` which is different to `29102265` Log the result into the console before your `if` statement and see what you get `console.log($(this).text());`

Comment: I changed the function to return a simple alert and still, nothing happened. Guess it is not the ===.